# How to get all values of given specific keys (for e.g: name) without loop from json?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to fetch all the names and label from JSON without loop. Is there a way to fetch with any filter method?

```
"sections": [
  {
    "id": "62ee1779",
    "name": "Drinks",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "1902b625",
        "name": "Cold Brew",       
        "optionSets": [
          {
            "id": "45f2a845-c83b-49c2-90ae-a227dfb7c513",
            "label": "Choose a size",
          },
          {
            "id": "af171c34-4ca8-4374-82bf-a418396e375c",
            "label": "Additional Toppings",
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  }
```

Comment: all the names as in within Section as well as within items?

Comment: Also post the desired format of the array you want

Comment: yes, @arjithn all the name in section as well items. Plus label in optionSets

Comment: ['Drink', 'Cold Brew', 'Choose a size', 'Additional Toppings']

Comment: You could use recursion but there is no consistency in the nesting array property name. It's called `items` at one level and `optionSets` in anther.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "without loops" I take it as without For Loops. because any kind of traversal of arrays, let alone nested traversal, involve iterating.
You can use the reduce method to have it done for you internally and give you the format you need.

Try this :

```js
const data = {
  sections: [
    {
      id: "62ee1779",
      name: "Drinks",
      items: [
        {
          id: "1902b625",
          name: "Cold Brew",
          optionSets: [
            {
              id: "45f2a845-c83b-49c2-90ae-a227dfb7c513",
              label: "Choose a size"
            },
            {
              id: "af171c34-4ca8-4374-82bf-a418396e375c",
              label: "Additional Toppings"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

x = data.sections.reduce((acc, ele) => {
  acc.push(ele.name);
  otherName = ele.items.reduce((acc2, elem2) => {
    acc2.push(elem2.name);
    label = elem2.optionSets.reduce((acc3, elem3) => {
      acc3.push(elem3.label);
      return acc3;
    }, []);
    return acc2.concat(label);
  }, []);
  return acc.concat(otherName);
}, []);

console.log(x);
```

Go ahead and press run snippet to see if this matches your desired output.
For More on info [reduce method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score -1):

In the context of cJSON

yes, we can fetch the key value for any of the object.

1 - each key value is pointed by one of the objects. will simply fetch that object and from there will get the key value.

In the above case for
**pre-requisition:** root must contain the json format and root must be the cJSON pointer. if not we can define it and use cJSON_Parse() to parse the json.

1st name object is "sections" will use

> cJSON *test = cJSON_GetObjectItem(root, "sections");
>
> char *name1 = cJSON_GetObjectItem(test, "name" )->valuestring;

2nd name key value

> cJSON *test2 = cJSON_GetObjectItem(test, "items");
>
> char *name2 = cJSON_GetObjectItem(tes2, "name")->valuestring;

likewise, we can do for others as well to fetch the key value.

Comment: Hi @dragon, I think he wants to use javascript and not c++

Comment: Hi @arjithn, yes already saw the label already before posting it. as this is an information sharing platform so this info might be helpful for that c developer who encountered the same scenario.

And I already mentioned in line 1 this is in context for cJSON.

No hard feelings.